# Google Sheet as Destination AND MYSQL as Source SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to know if it's possible to make Google Sheet as Destination from MYSQL Data as Source, so basically what I need is to export MYSQL data to Google Sheet, whereas I will be able to Update, Create, Insert and Delete Data in Google Sheets using ***"Script Component" and C# codes***.

I have used some components of SSIS like CDATA and COZYROC, It worked but it's only a trial, so I think it is better if I used Script Component using C# codes.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you could follow this documentation on how to use a C# script component to interact with google drive. Not quite sure about creating a native google sheets document though, but this site seems to have pretty good information to help: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet